# How to render HTML conditionally in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

```
var template = '';
template = template + '<div class="form-group col-lg-12">';
template = template + '<label  class="control-label"' + '' + object.required == true ? ' required' : '' + '>';
```

in above line `obj.required = true`. So, **true == true**

**Hence,** the template should have following html in the end

```
<div class="form-group col-lg-12"><label  class="control-label required">
```

But it returns only

```
">"
```

I belive my html embed code is not correct.
I did hard to find wrong but couldn't find.

Can you please find and suggest?

Comment: The way you are doing it is not angularjs specific, where in your angular app are you using the template? as ng-include with ngRoute module? Could you be more specific where you want to use the snippet and where `obj.required` is set/retrieved

Comment: May be i was not clear in my question title ... i am simply trying to generate an html code ... in my html i am checking object.required = true than add "required" to rendered html code else dont add.

Comment: In angular you just use HTML in a View. you don't need and you should not 'generate' it. You can control the DOM with directives like ng-show, ng-required etc. have a look at the answer by @pankajparkar and it gives you the right direction. If you want to know how to create a view, you should ask that, but after showing some research.

Comment: please keep aside angularJS.. just look at the problem i stated above.. do you have solution for that?

Comment: I posted an answer without the need for angular

Comment: Your question is still poorly described, without mentioning any limitations or reasons. Please improve the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most simple and best readable answer will be to use an `if` block:

```js
var object = {
  required: true
};
var template = '';

template += '<div class="form-group col-lg-12">';
template += '<label class="control-label"' + (object.required  ? ' required>' : '>');

document.body.innerText = template;
```

Comment: Thanks, that even i had written and works.. But the issue is when i try to use compact version if IF ELSE as i mentioned in my problem statement.

Comment: Well yes, you should lay out what actual problem you have more clearly. Why don't you even want to use the simple approach?

Comment: Super. thanks a lot. I also find my mistake i.e. i was either putting ')' wrong place or not putting it at all.

Answer (score 0):

Use `ng-attr` to render attribute based on condition

HTML

```
var template = '';
template = template + '<div class="form-group col-lg-12">';
template = template + '<label  class="control-label" ng-attr-required="' + object.required + '">';
```

Or simply use `ng-required="expression"`

```
var template = '';
template = template + '<div class="form-group col-lg-12">';
template = template + '<label  class="control-label" ng-required="' + object.required + '">';
```

Comment: I am trying to render simple html code with either it have required attribute or not based on if else condition.

Comment: You haven't mentioned you want it without angular..I thought your doing this in angular and going to compile this html inside angular,..